# I deployed my next project on vercel but it doesn't work(it works well in local)

Tags: javascript, next.js, prisma, supabase

I am building project with next.js and now I completed login and signup with prisma and supabase and deployed.
It works well in local but when I submit login form in vercel, I get 405 error(this method is not allowed).
What does the matter?
If you have any ideas, please let me know.
Thanks, everyone.

I thought this is cors error but it wasn't.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think code is unnecessary.
I will explain.
I made validToken api in page/api directory.
and it works well on vercel but login api doesn't work on vercel
The payload is correct but it cause 405 error.
I also set environment variable in vercel.
Really Strange!!!